# What tape backup device can read a DC 2120 XL cartridge?

Tags: linux, backup-restoration

While preparing to move to a new house, I came across two forgotten tape backup mini cartridges from 1996. I know they hold the only backup I made of my original Remote Access BBS, with all my original Star Trek themed ANSI art, DOS/OS2 shareware, and 1000+ users.

I'd love to be able to resurrect this time-capsule, but what hardware device can actually read this?

I think I originally used a 50pin Wide-SCSI external backup, narrower & longer than an external CD-Rom drive (caddy-style). Backup restoration software I'm not worried about as I'm certain I can find something on Linux to suffice, I just need to find the hardware ;)

Here is the mystery cartridge in question:

[image: DC 2120 XL Minicartridge]

The cartridge size is:

- 3 3/16"(w) x 2 3/8"(h) x 5/8"(d), or
- 8cm(w) x 6cm(h) x 1.5cm(d)

Thanks!

Comment: Great labeling scheme! "everything"

Comment: Can't be everything, it's also labeled "1/2". :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like a [1/4" QIC minicartridge](http://www.ndci.com/Home/NewsInfo/TapeFormats/tabid/92/Default.aspx). This particular form factor was apparently common in desktop computers.

Look for a QIC tape reader which was pulled out of somebody's desktop machine, and you may get lucky. I see several of them on eBay under $20.

Comment: Thanks for the lead, this sounds like what i'm looking for... Although you said "I see several of them on eBay under $20" would you mind posting a link? .. I don't see anything under $60, maybe I'm searching for the wrong term.

Comment: [1](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Iomega-640MB-QIC-Tape-Drive-IO3010-/200790632960) [2](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Colorado-250MB-QIC80-internal-tape-drive-/330763366279) Try searching for `QIC tape drive`.

Comment: Ah, there's different search results from your ebay.com and my ebay.ca :) .. thx!

Answer (score 0):

I was also the "SysOp" of a dial-up BBS, and a member of the RelayNet International Message Exchange from 1970 until 1977. The "Colorado Jumbo 250" and the "Conner Micro 250" were two of the tape drives that could/can read and write to the DC2120 mini tape cartages that were manufactured by 3M, Maxwell, and possibly other companies. The Colorado Jumbo 250's made a unique whirring sound when accessing the tape that I found fascinating; I was disappointed when the Conner tape drive did not make the same sound. If you do a Google search for "dc2120 tape drive", you may find that there are still several available for under $100.00.